# Tkinter program lagging and crashes after clicking many times

Tags: python, tkinter

Initalise

[Display of GUI after clicking many times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezh5a.png)

[Display of GUI before clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JBmv.png)

The error message that I got is failed to create the menu window

**Frame 1 Function**
def frames1(image_number):
global display_date
global display_time

```
display_time.grid_forget()
display_date.grid_forget()

display_date = Label(frame1,text = ws['A'+str(image_number)].value,padx=30,pady=10,bd=3,relief=SUNKEN,font=("Arial",12))
display_time = Label(frame1,text = ws['B'+str(image_number)].value,padx=30,pady=10,bd=3,relief=SUNKEN,font=("Arial",12))




display_date.grid(row=1,column=1)

display_time.grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=3)
```

**Forward Button**
def forward(image_number):
global button_forward
global button_back

```
frames1(image_number)

button_forward = Button(frame1,text = ">>",command = lambda:forward(image_number + 1 ),font=('Arial',15),padx=5)
button_back = Button(frame1,text = "<<",command = lambda:back(image_number - 1),font=('Arial',15),padx=5)

button_back.grid(row=1,column=0)
button_forward.grid(row=1,column=2)
```

**Back Button**
def back(image_number):

```
global button_forward
global button_back

frames1(image_number)

button_forward = Button(frame1,text = ">>",command = lambda:forward(image_number + 1 ),font=('Arial',15),padx=5)
button_back = Button(frame1,text = "<<",command = lambda:back(image_number - 1),font=('Arial',15),padx=5)

button_back.grid(row=1,column=0)
button_forward.grid(row=1,column=2)
```

**Frame 1 initalise**

```
time = str(ws['B3'].value)
display_date = str(ws['A3'].value)
display_time = Label(frame1,text = time,padx=30,pady=10,bd=3,relief=SUNKEN,font= ("Arial",12))


button_back = Button(frame1,text="<<",command = back,font=('Arial',15),padx=5)
display_date = Label(frame1,text = display_date,padx=30,pady=10,bd=3,relief=SUNKEN,font=("Arial",12))
button_forward = Button(frame1,text = ">>",command = lambda:forward(int(4)),font=('Arial',15))
Label(frame1,text='Log 1 of '+str(ws['DF3'].value),bg='grey').grid(row=3,column=0,columnspan=3)

button_back.grid(row=1,column=0)
display_date.grid(row=1,column=1)
button_forward.grid(row=1,column=2)
display_time.grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=3)
root.mainloop()
```

What do I do to solve this problem? I can click more times when there is lesser frames for some reason.

Comment: Please post the full traceback of any / all errors you're getting

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the code. Also, it's best if you have a single block of runnable code that we can copy and paste.

Comment: At least part of the problem appears to be that each time you click a button you create a new button. Over time you're going to have hundreds or thousands of buttons stacked on top of each other.